# How to provide Disclosure button only for a subset of items in a List?

Tags: extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a requirement in which I need to add the disclosure button only for some of the items in a Sencha List . Any idea on how this can be done?

Setting onItemDisclosure to TRUE enable this option for all items in the list. But I want to enable it only for a subset based on certain conditions.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use List's [disclosureProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-disclosureProperty). From the docs:

A property to check on each record to display the disclosure on a per record basis. This property must be false to prevent the disclosure from being displayed on the item.

Defaults to: 'disclosure'

So adding field called `disclosure` to your model should be all you need to do.

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',

    fields:[//other fields
        {
            name:'disclosure',
            convert: function(value, record){
                // logic to determine if disclosure should be displayed.
                // return Boolean value
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks for quick help. I have put debugger in convert() but store doesn't get loaded when debuuger is being hit. I am not able to put my logic to check if list row need to show disclosure button or not. please help.

Comment: Your comment is unclear. Are you saying the convert method is hit in the debugger, but not when the store is loaded? Or are you saying the convert method is never hit while debugging? How are you setting up your store and model? Does your store use the model or are you just specifying a list of field names in the store and having Ext automatically generate the model for you?

Comment: I am new to Sencha Touch.my Store uses a model that is in Model folder and when debugger is hit Model doesn't have loaded.

Comment: The `value` passed into the convert function is not the value of status, it is the value of the disclosure property in your json blob (undefined or null since you aren't sending it and are creating it from nothing right now). If you want to get the value of the status field, grab it off the record passed in. `if (record.get('status') === "Live! Train Status") { /* ... */ }`